# How to change the version of a "son dependency" in pom?

Tags: maven

there is another way to change the version of a maven dependency that is onto another dependency?
i did that like this and works fine but, i want to know if there's another way more cleaner to do that.

Example:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Dependency that i want to update -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the best practice is to do this with [dependencyManagement](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management), and only set the version for the dependency (not scope). This will enforce the version of the dependency with minimal effect on the dependency tree.
Adding a direct dependency like you do now, wrongfully signals that your code refers to jackson-annotations apis directly, and may also have side effects on the set of transitive dependencies.

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  ...
```

Btw, I think that the exclusion in your example is unnecessary. You can verify that by running `mvn dependency:tree`.